# Why this "syntax error at or near "user"" error trying to insert a new record using the save() method from JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot project using **Spring Data JPA** and **Hibernate** but I am finding some difficulties trying to perform a simple **INSERT** query using the **save()** method of the **JpaRepository** interface.

As database I am using **PostgreSQL**, here I have the follosing table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."User"
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    middle_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    surname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sex "char" NOT NULL,
    birthdate date NOT NULL,
    tax_code character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    e_mail character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    contact_number character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "User_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

that I have mapped into an thie **User** entity class in my project, this one:

```
package com.easydefi.users.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tex_code")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    private String eMail;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    
}
```

Ok, the I created this **UserRepository** interface extenging the **JpaRepository** intreface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

At the moment it is empty because I was trying to perform a first test of the **save()** method.

Finnally I created this simple test class containing a method to test the operation related to the insertion of a new record into the **User** table, this:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void TestInsertUser()
    {
        User user = new User("Mario", null, "Rossi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }

}
```

the problem is that performing this method I obtain the following exception\error in my stacktrace:

```
2021-11-03 12:19:28.563  WARN 8094 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2021-11-03 12:19:28.567 ERROR 8094 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 13
2021-11-03 12:19:32.058  INFO 8094 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-03 12:19:32.065  INFO 8094 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-03 12:19:32.080  INFO 8094 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

The problem is that it speack about a generic **syntax error at or near "user"** but I can not understand what is the problem.

What is the problem? How can I try to fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please share more logs (before error) and your jpa config (if any)

Comment: My educated guess is that it's because `USER` is a [reseved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You could try to add `@javax.persistence.Table(name = "\"User\"")` to your Entity class.

Comment: I second that the error is probably because USER is a reserved word and at some point in your sql generation it does not get escaped correctly. Errors like this is why I would always strongly suggest not using keywords like USER, PASSWORD etc as table or column names. Calling a table USER_DATA instead will save one a lot of potential trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, `user` is a reserved SQL keyword. You can change the name of the table to another word or you can use the "" tricks, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: May I ask why you don't recommend escaping the table name via @Table annotation?

Comment: If you already know that was a reserved word, just use another. @Table(name="`users`"), this usage looks weird to me and i mostly do not use table annottation so it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

"user" is a reserved keyword in PostgresSQL. Either change the table's name of User to something else or use double quotes to escape it.

```
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
```